# Using preg_replace to parse HTML

Tags: php, html, html-parsing, preg-replace

I am looking for a regular expression to convert any text line that begins with a `-` (dash) into a bullet point (`<li>`).

For example:

```
- This is a point
- This is another point
```

Becomes:

```html
<li>This is a point</li>
<li>This is another point</li>
```

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: i've heard preg_replace cannot parse HTML

Answer (score 2):

We do not give out code, we help answer any questions.

---

This is my answer to helping you do what your trying to achieve.

Take a look at [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php), it returns false if what you were looking for was not found. Now you can create an IF statement.

Run a loop if it did not return false. As for as replacing is concerned take a look at [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). You could also use [strlen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) to find out how many letters total which may help your case.

---

Again, this ^ is only a quick boost to help you achieve your goal. I hope you do take my advice to not ask for code.

**Also**: Why not do some google searches? I'm pretty sure someone's already done what your trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

Markdown does that for you, there is a [port for PHP by Michel Fortin](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/).

It also converts *this* to *this* and **this** to **this**. For a full list, see [the official Markdown site](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use regexp groups.

```
preg_replace('/^- (.*)$/m', '<li> \1 </li>', $string);
```

The 'm' at the end of the regexp here ensures that the '^' and '$' meta-characters match the beginnings and endings of lines.  The parenthesized portion of the pattern captures the text it matches so that it can be used later in the replace string.  In this case '\1' refers to the grouping started by the first parentheses in the pattern.